# How can i turn text to link version with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want turn those texts to link type versions;

```
nis silence => NisSilence
şalk priori => SalkPriori
Sanchez404 Sad Mood => Sanchez404SadMood
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? can you add that to the question?

Comment: You can first capitalize the first letter in every word, then remove the space. Yes, by using javascript.

Comment: Look into [`.normalize("NFKD")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize), [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods) methods (both static and on prototype), [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#instance_methods) methods, and [`toLocaleUpperCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleUpperCase) or `toUpperCase`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put separated words like "nis silence", "şalk priori" etc into TitleCase format. You could start by creating an array of words using [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) then capitalize the first character of each word in the array and remove the space between each word using [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

To remove the accents and diacritics from the strings you can use [`String.prototype.normalize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) and [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  let strArr = str.split(" ");
  for (var i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
    strArr[i] = strArr[i][0].toUpperCase().concat(strArr[i].substr(1).toLowerCase());
    strArr[i] = strArr[i].normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
  }
  return strArr.join("");
}

console.log(titleCase("nis silence"));
console.log(titleCase("şalk priori"));
console.log(titleCase("Sanchez404 SAD Mood"));
```

Another option, like @JavaScript mentioned would be using [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in place of the `for` loop.

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  let strArr = str.split(" ");
  return strArr.map(s => s[0].toUpperCase()
   .concat(s.substr(1).toLowerCase())).join("")
   .normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
}

console.log(titleCase("nis silence"));
console.log(titleCase("şalk priori"));
console.log(titleCase("Sanchez404 SAD Mood"));
```